# PyQt unable to add tableWIdget to existing application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have an existing application to which I would like to add a table widget. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to add a PyQt5 table following this [tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-table/).

My code is as follows:

```
class App(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.player = QMediaPlayer()        # QMediaPlayer class allows the playing of a media source.
    self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()    # QMediaPlaylist class provides a list of media content to play.
    self.title = 'PyTunes'
    self.left = 300
    self.top = 300
    self.width = 300
    self.height = 150
    self.color = 0  # 0- toggle to dark 1- toggle to light
    self.userAction = -1  # 0- stopped, 1- playing 2-paused
    self.setup_UI()

def setup_UI(self):
    # Add file menu
    menubar = self.menuBar()
    filemenu = menubar.addMenu('File')
    windowmenu = menubar.addMenu('Window')

    help_act = QAction('Open Help', self)
    folder_act = QAction('Open Folder', self)
    theme_act = QAction('Toggle light/dark theme', self)

    folder_act.setShortcut('Ctrl+D')
    help_act.setShortcut('Ctrl+H')
    theme_act.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')

    filemenu.addAction(folder_act)
    filemenu.addAction(help_act)
    windowmenu.addAction(theme_act)

    help_act.triggered.connect(self.open_help)
    folder_act.triggered.connect(self.add_files)
    theme_act.triggered.connect(self.toggle_colors)

    self.add_controls()
    self.createTable()

    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    self.toggle_colors()
    self.show()

def add_controls(self):
    wid = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(wid)

    # Add song controls
    volumeslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
    volumeslider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    volumeslider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.change_volume)
    volumeslider.setValue(100)

    play_btn = QPushButton('Play')  # play button
    pause_btn = QPushButton('Pause')  # pause button
    stop_btn = QPushButton('Stop')  # stop button

    # Add playlist controls
    prev_btn = QPushButton('Prev')
    shuffle_btn = QPushButton('Shuffle')
    next_btn = QPushButton('Next')
    sort_btn = QPushButton('Sort')
    search_btn = QPushButton('Search')
    remove_btn = QPushButton('Remove')

    # Add button layouts
    control_area = QVBoxLayout()  # centralWidget
    controls = QHBoxLayout()
    playlist_ctrl_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    playlist_func = QHBoxLayout()

    # Add buttons to song controls layout
    controls.addWidget(play_btn)
    controls.addWidget(pause_btn)
    controls.addWidget(stop_btn)

    # Add buttons to playlist controls layout
    playlist_ctrl_layout.addWidget(prev_btn)
    playlist_ctrl_layout.addWidget(shuffle_btn)
    playlist_ctrl_layout.addWidget(next_btn)

    playlist_func.addWidget(sort_btn)
    playlist_func.addWidget(search_btn)
    playlist_func.addWidget(remove_btn)

    # Add to vertical layout
    control_area.addLayout(controls)
    control_area.addLayout(playlist_ctrl_layout)
    control_area.addWidget(volumeslider)
    control_area.addLayout(playlist_func)

    # control_area.addWidget(QTableWidget)   
    # control_area.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    wid.setLayout(control_area)

    # Connect each signal to their appropriate function
    play_btn.clicked.connect(self.play_handler)
    pause_btn.clicked.connect(self.pause_handler)
    stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_handler)

    prev_btn.clicked.connect(self.prev_song)
    shuffle_btn.clicked.connect(self.shuffle_list)
    next_btn.clicked.connect(self.next_song)

    sort_btn.clicked.connect(self.sort_handler)
    search_btn.clicked.connect(self.search_handler)
    remove_btn.clicked.connect(self.remove_handler)

    self.statusBar()
    # Signal emitted when current media changes. Call song_changed
    self.playlist.currentMediaChanged.connect(self.song_changed)

def createTable(self):
    # Create table
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,1)"))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,2)"))
    self.tableWidget.move(0, 0)

    # table selection change
    self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    print("\n")
    for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())
```

I added the box layout in add_controls() and now I am trying to add the table to the box layout.

I have tried: `control_area.addWidget(QTableWidget)` but this returns the error:

> ```
> control_area.addWidget(QTableWidget)
> ```
>
> TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'

I have also tried: `control_area.addWidget(self.tableWidget)` but this returns the error:

> control_area.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
>   AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'tableWidget'

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong and how this can be rectified? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.createTable()` right before `control_area.addWidget(self.tableWidget)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player   = QMediaPlayer()     # QMediaPlayer class allows the playing of a media source.
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()   # QMediaPlaylist class provides a list of media content to play.
        self.title    = 'PyTunes'
        self.left   = 300
        self.top    = 300
        self.width  = 300
        self.height = 150
        self.color  = 0       # 0- toggle to dark 1- toggle to light
        self.userAction = -1  # 0- stopped, 1- playing 2-paused

        self.setup_UI()

    def setup_UI(self):
        # Add file menu
        menubar    = self.menuBar()
        filemenu   = menubar.addMenu('File')
        windowmenu = menubar.addMenu('Window')

        help_act   = QAction('Open Help', self)
        folder_act = QAction('Open Folder', self)
        theme_act  = QAction('Toggle light/dark theme', self)

        folder_act.setShortcut('Ctrl+D')
        help_act.setShortcut(  'Ctrl+H')
        theme_act.setShortcut( 'Ctrl+T')

        filemenu.addAction(folder_act)
        filemenu.addAction(help_act)
        windowmenu.addAction(theme_act)

#        help_act.triggered.connect(  self.open_help)
#        folder_act.triggered.connect(self.add_files)
#        theme_act.triggered.connect( self.toggle_colors)

        self.add_controls()

        self.createTable()

        self.control_area.addWidget(self.tableWidget)                  # <===============

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
#?        self.toggle_colors()
        self.show()

    def add_controls(self):
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        # Add song controls
        volumeslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        volumeslider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
#        volumeslider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.change_volume)
        volumeslider.setValue(100)

        play_btn  = QPushButton('Play')  # play button
        pause_btn = QPushButton('Pause')  # pause button
        stop_btn  = QPushButton('Stop')  # stop button

        # Add playlist controls
        prev_btn    = QPushButton('Prev')
        shuffle_btn = QPushButton('Shuffle')
        next_btn    = QPushButton('Next')
        sort_btn    = QPushButton('Sort')
        search_btn  = QPushButton('Search')
        remove_btn  = QPushButton('Remove')

        # Add button layouts
        self.control_area = QVBoxLayout()                    # + self.            
        controls     = QHBoxLayout()
        playlist_ctrl_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        playlist_func = QHBoxLayout()

        # Add buttons to song controls layout
        controls.addWidget(play_btn)
        controls.addWidget(pause_btn)
        controls.addWidget(stop_btn)

        # Add buttons to playlist controls layout
        playlist_ctrl_layout.addWidget(prev_btn)
        playlist_ctrl_layout.addWidget(shuffle_btn)
        playlist_ctrl_layout.addWidget(next_btn)

        playlist_func.addWidget(sort_btn)
        playlist_func.addWidget(search_btn)
        playlist_func.addWidget(remove_btn)

        # Add to vertical layout
        self.control_area.addLayout(controls)                # + self. 
        self.control_area.addLayout(playlist_ctrl_layout)    # + self. 
        self.control_area.addWidget(volumeslider)            # + self. 
        self.control_area.addLayout(playlist_func)           # + self. 

        # control_area.addWidget(QTableWidget)   
        # control_area.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        wid.setLayout(self.control_area)                     # + self. 

        # Connect each signal to their appropriate function
#        play_btn.clicked.connect(self.play_handler)
#        pause_btn.clicked.connect(self.pause_handler)
#        stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_handler)

#        prev_btn.clicked.connect(self.prev_song)
#        shuffle_btn.clicked.connect(self.shuffle_list)
#        next_btn.clicked.connect(self.next_song)

#        sort_btn.clicked.connect(self.sort_handler)
#        search_btn.clicked.connect(self.search_handler)
#        remove_btn.clicked.connect(self.remove_handler)

        self.statusBar()
        # Signal emitted when current media changes. Call song_changed
#        self.playlist.currentMediaChanged.connect(self.song_changed)

    def createTable(self):
        # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.move(0, 0)

        # table selection change
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("\n")
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), 
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), 
                  currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = App()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved, issue was here:

```
self.add_controls()
self.createTable()
```

since I was calling `add_controls()` before creating the table, resulting in:

> 'App' object has no attribute 'tableWidget'

Comment: Sure, the error message points that the table instance is not created yet.